# Do I need to hold on to Toorum's notes for any purpose?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

So far in my journeys I've come across a bunch of Toorum's notes.  Are they purely flavor text or do they serve some purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are purely flavor, they do nothing more. My previous answer talked about an achievement that was incorrect, this is not true. The achievement I thought I unlocked by finding all the notes was: (spoiler)

> For finding Toorum's body on level 10, it just so happens that near his body contains  his last 2 notes.

which unlocks the "Buddies with Toorum" achievement. This allows you to play as Toorum in future playthroughs. More information on that can be found [here](http://www.gamebanshee.com/legendofgrimrock/walkthrough/toorummode.php).

Comment: Please clarify: Do you need to have them all in your inventory at once to get the achievement, or do you just have to have held them individually at some point?

Comment: @Alex I was wrong about the achievement, it is unlocked from something else which just so happens as you find the last note.

Comment: thanks for updating it, looking forward to trying toorum solo next playthrough

Comment: +1 thanks for answering the question, the notes are really cluttering up my inventory..